# Decode Barcode from Image in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, camera, win-universal-app, qr-code

I'm realize an universal windows app on windows tablet (windows 10).
This tablet have camera and i want take a photo of qr code and decode it.

So i've tried with Zxing.net, but doesn't work on universal windows app.
There's a method to decode a qr code inside a foto.

```
 var bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
                var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
                var size = new Size(bounds.Width * scaleFactor, bounds.Height * scaleFactor);

                CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
                captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
                captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(size.Width, size.Height);

                StorageFile file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    //QR code conversion from jepg and return string.
                }
```

I've visited some links...for example: 
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile
and 
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=zxingnet#trunk/Clients/WindowsRTDemo/Package.appxmanifest

But nothing work for universal windows app.
Solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But nothing work for universal windows app

By testing on my side the [sample](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Clients/WindowsRTDemo) you linked do works.

Since you didn't provide your code snippet that decode the bar-code, so that I provide the whole project that can work well on my side that you could test and try to find what's wrong with your code snippet.

Install the [`ZXing.uwp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.uwp/) nuget package firstly, and testing with the following code snippet.

XAML

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Image x:Name="imgshow" Height="150" Width="150"></Image>
   <TextBox x:Name="txtDecoderType"  Height="50" Width="250"></TextBox>
   <TextBox x:Name="txtDecoderContent"  Height="50" Width="250"></TextBox>
   <Button x:Name="btnscan" Click="btnscan_Click" Content=" scan"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private async void btnscan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
    var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    var size = new Size(bounds.Width * scaleFactor, bounds.Height * scaleFactor);
    CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(size.Width, size.Height);
    StorageFile file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    if (file != null)
    {
        //QR code conversion from jepg and return string.
        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;    
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);                
            writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
            writeableBitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
            imgshow.Source = writeableBitmap;
        }
        // create a barcode reader instance
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        // detect and decode the barcode inside the  writeableBitmap
        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            Options = { TryHarder = true }
        }; 
        Result result = reader.Decode(writeableBitmap);
        // do something with the result
        if (result != null)
        {
            txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
            txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, from 1803, UWP also provide APIs for  *Barcode scanner*, details please reference [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-barcodescanner) and the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner).